# KKT conditions for min-cost flow QP

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I'm working on a convex quadratic separable min-cost flow problem with the following structure:

$P = \{\min \frac{1}{2}x^tQx + qx : Ex = b, 0 \leq x \leq u\}$

But I'm stuck on deriving the KKT conditions to solve the problem.

Can someone help me with the computation?

Comment: $\min$ seems to be missing before 1/2.

Comment: yes thank you! corrected!

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KKT condition is given by introducing relaxation parameters to the objective (derivative equals 0) so that whenever any element of $x$ is above $0$ or below $u$, parameters can increase to allow the system of equations to satisfy but at the same time cause penalties when x is not optimal.

So we have the following linear system that needs to be solved.
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
Q & E^\mathrm{T} & -I & I \\
E & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
\lambda \\
\mu \\
h \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-q\\
b\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The KKT conditions are then the above equation for stationary.
Your listed conditions for primal feasibility.

complementary slackness:

$$\mu\odot x=0$$

$$h\odot(x-u)=0$$

And $\lambda\ge0,\ \mu\ge0,\ h\ge0$ for dual feasibility.

This is my first ever answer on here. Hope I don't make a mistake.

Comment: it looks as if there is an error in the last 2 row of the matrix above, as they together would imply $\mu=0=u$.

Comment: This answer is not correct. For example, the system contains the condition $x=0$ which would be too restrictive.

Comment: @Dima Pasechnik They are actually complementary slackness that don't need to be satisfied. Only the feasibility equations and the stationary point need to be satisfied.